# Good Book for Learning WPF using C# in Beginner's point of view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to learn “WPF using C#” properly.

I read basic concept of WPF using C# language. Since I know C++ and HTML It did not took too much time to read C#  and XAML simple tutorial.

Now when I searched for the WPF tutorial, most of the sites give WPF features and some of the .net controls API and class usage.

But I want a book which will Guide a beginner in a proper way

Please any body suggest me a good book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Pro WPF in C# 2010: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4***
[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2010-Presentation-Foundation/dp/1430272058](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272058)

[image: Cover image]

It is a very up-to-date book, and I learned WPF from it in 2008. It's for beginners, but covers everything, from "what is user32, what is gdi+ and what is directx" to "how to implement your own plugin system in a WPF app". The only missing part is the MVVM pattern explanation, thought it thoroughly deals with Data-Binding concepts.

*Extracted from amazon:*

> **What you'll learn**
>
> - WPF basics: XAML, layout, control    essentials, and data flow
> - WPF applications: Navigation,    commands, localization, and
>     deployment
> - Advanced controls: Custom controls, menus, toolbars, and trees
> - WPF documents: Text layout, printing, and document packaging
> - Graphics and multimedia: Drawing shapes, sound and video, animation,
>     geometric transformations, and imaging
> - *(note from me)* I would also add Data-Binding as a strong 'plus' of
>     this book
>
> **Who is this book for?**
>
> This book is designed for developers
>   encountering WPF for the first time in
>   their professional lives. A working
>   knowledge of C# and the basic
>   architecture of .NET is helpful to
>   follow the examples easily, but all
>   concepts will be explained from the
>   ground up.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, please can you refer me some idea to start with.

Comment: This book wasn't really good for me because it was more of a reference book rather than a kind of "text book" for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

[Programming WPF](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510374) is really good to begin with

Answer (score 1):

WPF4 Unleashed from Adam Nathan. the best wpf book i know.

[WPF4 Unleashed Link](http://www.amazon.de/WPF-4-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672331195)